Enigmatic Puzzle: Locks in Clocks
Here's a new enigmatic puzzle that I've been working on. I had someone play test it last week and it required some revisions, but I think it's all set now. If for some reason it still doesn't quite work out, I apologize in advance.
Clock Picking
How long must I wait between the clicks just to get mixed up?

In case the image isn't showing up well for you, here's a description: This is an image of a combination lock with 60 numbers inside of a standard analog clock. There are four such clock/locks in the first row, two in the second row, and two in the third row. The combinations are:
17-57-22, 58-48-28, 3-13-48, 32-42-57
46-26-1, 29-34-49
38-53-58, 44-44-29
